# Swift: Why ?? can not use for String?

Tags: swift

I got this error:

> Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'UUID'

here:

```swift
Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'UUID'
```

Why? `??` is for optionals, not?

Comment: The error message clearly answers this imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) and [UUID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/uuid) are not the same types, so they cannot be compared.

If you want to compare them, you could get the value of the UUID as a String using the UUID.uuidString property.

```swift
let x: String? = nil
let uuid = UUID()

let y: String = x ?? uuid.uuidString
```

Answer (score -2):

first, get device UDID as a String after that you can compare

```
let udid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```